# Google cloud storage, public objects but not public project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have a google storage bucket to store files, some of folders I want to make public, the others not.

So I can set "allUsers" as viewer, but for whole bucket. But even if I make for whole bucket, users can see the list of all files if they go straight to bucket url.

What I have.

```
bucket / 
   images/
   pdfs/
   docx/
```

So I want the images folder be public and access only with direct link, the rest not. Is there any such kind of config?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set public access by object on the bucket, then only set the images folder to be public. So don't make the bucket public, just the images folder. That should do what you want. Should all be doable from the google cloud console.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set only one folder from a bucket to be public, [you either set individual files or the whole bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public).

The options I can think of are:

1. Create a separated public bucket for the images
2. Keep the bucket private and only make public the files inside the images folder:

   `gsutil acl ch -u AllUsers:R gs://[BUCKET-NAME]/images/*`